# Mongoose pre updateOne hook is not invoked while doc is updated

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have this schema and fields like `basicSalary` can be edited by admin through dashboard UI, the pre save hook works fine to calculate fields, followed by pre updateOne hook to update the doc when it's edited by admin

```
const salariesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  employeeId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "employee",
    required: true,
  },
  month: { type: String, required: true },
  year: { type: String, required: true },
  basicSalary: { type: Number, default: 0, required: true },
  accomodation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  transportation: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  bonus: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  SSC: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  incomeTax: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  medicalInsurance: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  loan: { type: Number, default: 0, default: null },
  totalEarnings: { type: Number },
  totalDeductions: { type: Number },
  netSalary: { type: Number },
});
salariesSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  this.SSC = this.basicSalary * 0.07;
  this.totalEarnings =
    this.basicSalary + this.accomodation + this.transportation + this.bonus;
  this.totalDeductions =
    this.incomeTax + this.medicalInsurance + this.loan + this.SSC;
  this.netSalary = this.totalEarnings - this.totalDeductions;
  next();
});

salariesSchema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {
  this.SSC = this.basicSalary * 0.07;
  this.totalEarnings =
    this.basicSalary + this.accomodation + this.transportation + this.bonus;
  this.totalDeductions =
    this.incomeTax + this.medicalInsurance + this.loan + this.SSC;
  this.netSalary = this.totalEarnings - this.totalDeductions;
  next();
});
```

**routes > salary..js**

```
const Salary = require("../models/Salary");

const editSalary = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salary = Salary.findById(req.body._id);
    await salary.updateOne({ $set: req.body });
    res.status(200).json("salary has been updated successfully");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).json(err);
  }
};
```

if admin for example increased `basicSalary` by 50, `totalEarnings`and `netSalary` values should also be updated by 50 based on the calculations in `pre updateOne` hook, but that doesn't work, what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turned out that i can't access fields directly by using `this.fieldName`, i solved it by using `this.get("fieldName")` converted into a number, and using `this.set` ( see documentation ) instead of `return fieldName = expression`

**let me know if you have a better way to do it**

```
salariesSchema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {
  this.set({ SSC: Number(this.get("basicSalary")) * 0.07 });
  this.set({
    totalDeductions:
      Number(this.get("incomeTax")) +
      Number(this.get("medicalInsurance")) +
      Number(this.get("loan")) +
      Number(this.get("SSC")),
  });

  this.set({
    totalEarnings:
      Number(this.get("basicSalary")) +
      Number(this.get("accomodation")) +
      Number(this.get("transportation")) +
      Number(this.get("bonus")),
  });

  this.set({
    netSalary:
      Number(this.get("totalEarnings")) - Number(this.get("totalDeductions")),
  });

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create separate `pre` hook for other types of queries. For example, you can add **updateOne** `pre` hook:

```js
salariesSchema.pre("save", function (next) {
  this.SSC = this.basicSalary * 0.07;
  this.totalEarnings =
    this.basicSalary + this.accomodation + this.transportation + this.bonus;
  this.totalDeductions =
    this.incomeTax + this.medicalInsurance + this.loan + this.SSC;
  this.netSalary = this.totalEarnings - this.totalDeductions;
  next();
});

salariesSchema.pre('updateOne', function() {
  this.SSC = this.basicSalary * 0.07;
  this.totalEarnings =
    this.basicSalary + this.accomodation + this.transportation + this.bonus;
  this.totalDeductions =
    this.incomeTax + this.medicalInsurance + this.loan + this.SSC;
  this.netSalary = this.totalEarnings - this.totalDeductions;
  next();
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you try again?

Comment: oh i see, that was my first attempt, but it doesn't work, if i change for example ```basicSalary``` and increased its value by 50, ```totalEarnings``` value suppose to increase by 50, but it doesn't

Comment: But are you using `updateOne` method for updating, or maybe some other method? Maybe `findByIdAndUpdate`?

Comment: i use ```findById``` then ```updateOne```, i updated my post and added code, can you please see it